# getting invisible recaptcha to trigger on page load

Tags: jquery, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to make a simple page that does an invisible recaptcha check, and if successful, alerts the received token. Despite several attempts I did not get this to work. I made a minimal example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var recaptchaCallback = function(token) {
            alert(token);
        };
    </script>
    <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='MY_KEY' data-callback='recaptchaCallback' data-size='invisible'></div>
    <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            grecaptcha.execute();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript engine errors saying that "grecaptcha is not defined". If I replace that line by

```
setTimeout(function() {grecaptcha.execute();}, 1000);
```

then the program functions as expected, however that is very unstable. How can I tell jQuery to actually wait for the google recaptcha code to fully load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently by-passed the issue by using

```
var ticker = setInterval(function(){
    try{
        grecaptcha.execute();
        clearInterval(ticker);
    } catch(e) {}
},100);
```

but if anyone has a more elegant solution I'd still welcome hearing about it.